# Concurrent writes to System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, bitmap

I have a large (>100MB) Bitmap that I need to write to from multiple threads simultaneously. Each thread has his own region in the image he'll be writing to.

My original idea was to hand each thread a BitmapData returned by Bitmap.LockBits with a different rectangle for each thread. This however throws a "System.InvalidOperationException: Bitmap region is already locked.", even though there are no overlapping regions.

A small code example, single threaded but it proves my point:

```
{
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(16, 8, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
     var data1 = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 8, 8), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
     var data2 = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(8, 0, 8, 8), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb); // throws                
}
```

In this code example, the last statement throws an exception. Unless my count is off, both rectangles should be contained in the original bitmap and should not overlap.

Should I lock the entire image with one LockBits and then write to that BitmapData from without concern for thread safety? I copy my data into the Bitmap using a Marshal.Copy().

Comment: Closed. There is already a thread about this exact problem with all dicussions.